# Python SyntaxError :'return' outside function

Tags: python

Compiler showed:

```
File "temp.py", line 56
    return result
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Where was I wrong?

```
class Complex (object):
    def __init__(self, realPart, imagPart):
        self.realPart = realPart
        self.imagPart = imagPart            

    def __str__(self):
        if type(self.realPart) == int and type(self.imagPart) == int:
            if self.imagPart >=0:
                return '%d+%di'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
            elif self.imagPart <0:
                return '%d%di'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)   
    else:
        if self.imagPart >=0:
                return '%f+%fi'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
            elif self.imagPart <0:
                return '%f%fi'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)

        def __div__(self, other):
            r1 = self.realPart
            i1 = self.imagPart
            r2 = other.realPart
            i2 = other.imagPart
            resultR = float(float(r1*r2+i1*i2)/float(r2*r2+i2*i2))
            resultI = float(float(r2*i1-r1*i2)/float(r2*r2+i2*i2))
            result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
            return result

c1 = Complex(2,3)
c2 = Complex(1,4)
print c1/c2
```

What about this?

```
class Complex (object):
    def __init__(self, realPart, imagPart):
        self.realPart = realPart
        self.imagPart = imagPart            

    def __str__(self):
        if type(self.realPart) == int and type(self.imagPart) == int:
            if self.imagPart >=0:
                return '%d+%di'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
            elif self.imagPart <0:
                return '%d%di'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
        else:
            if self.imagPart >=0:
                return '%f+%fi'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
            elif self.imagPart <0:
                return '%f%fi'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)

    def __div__(self, other):
        r1 = self.realPart
        i1 = self.imagPart
        r2 = other.realPart
        i2 = other.imagPart
        resultR = float(float(r1*r2+i1*i2)/float(r2*r2+i2*i2))
        resultI = float(float(r2*i1-r1*i2)/float(r2*r2+i2*i2))
        result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
        return result

c1 = Complex(2,3)
c2 = Complex(1,4)
print c1/c2
```

Comment: Your indention is inconsistent. Use four spaces per indention level as recommended by PEP-8.

Comment: @Tichodroma I've updated the code as above. But it still shows 'return' outside function ...

Comment: You still have inconsistend indention. Please use *four* spaces for each level of indention. Right now you still have four and eight spaces mixed.

Comment: @Tichodroma OK now all the code follows four spaces rule.

Answer (score 17):

I would check my indentation, it looks off. Are you possibly mixing tabs and spaces? The [PEP8 (Python Style Guide)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using [4 spaces only](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). Unlike other languages, whitepace makes a big difference in Python, so consistency is important.

The above also makes the following recommendation:

> When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option,
>   it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces.
>   When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly
>   recommended!

In particular, your 2nd `else` seems to be off (probably should be indented), and  this method `def __div__(self, other):` too (which I would think ought to be at the same level as your other `def`s - i.e., moved "out" rather than indented).

Problems mixing tabs/blanks are easy to have since both characters are "invisible".

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your `__div__` is declared at the same level as your `__str__` (right now, it's declared inside the `__str_`).

Answer (score 3):

By my copy and paste, everything from this line:

```
else:
if self.imagPart >=0:
        return '%f+%fi'%(self.realPart, self.imagPart)
elif self.imagPart <0: # Everything under here..
```

To this line:

```
    resultI = float(float(r2*i1-r1*i2)/float(r2*r2+i2*i2))
result = Complex(resultR, resultI)
return result # Needs to be unindented.
```

has wrong indenting.

Answer (score 2):

Well i am new to python world. What i learned is return statement should be some thing like this.

Example one :-

```
def split_train_test(data, test_ratio):
    shuffled_indices = np.random.permutation(len(data))
    test_set_size = int(len(data) * test_ratio)
    test_indices = shuffled_indices[:test_set_size]
    train_indices = shuffled_indices[test_set_size:]
    return data.iloc[train_indices],data.iloc[test_indices]
```

Example two :-

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

I answered here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47377418/2298357

Answer (score 0):

```
def functiont(x,y z,k):
    """some function
    """
    if xxxx:
        return True
    else
        return False
```

As per the code above you can see the `return` statement is indented inside the function def and hence there will be no error in this case. However, you will get an python error -  **SyntaxError :'return' outside function** if the return is indented as below.

```
def functiont(x,y z,k):
    """some function
    """
if xxxx:
    return True
else
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use a good editor

Install one of the below editors that can format your files properly

- PyCharm Community edition,  https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/
- Visual Studio code, https://code.visualstudio.com/

> Format document

For example:  In Visual Studio code, Open the file > Right click > Format document

> Finding & Fixing the issue

Once the code is formatted by editor, you will see something like below

**Bad code**

```
def func1():
    print ("I am in func1")
    return ""               # <----------- this is ok, its inside function func1

def func2():
    print ("I am in func2")
return ""                   # <-----CASE 1------ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function 'func2'

print ("I am outside of all functions")
return ""                   # <-----CASE 2------ SyntaxError: 'return' outside of all functions
```

NOTE - In both CASE 1 & CASE 2, ERROR occurred because 'return' is not inside any function, it's outside of all functions.

**Good code**

```
def func1():
    print ("I am in func1")
    return ""           # <----------- this is ok, its inside function func1

def func2():
    print ("I am in func2")
    return ""           # <-----CASE 1-- Fixed, added SPACE or TAB, now 'return' is inside function

print ("I am outside of all functions")
                        # <-----CASE 2-- Fixed, 'return' is removed, no return is required here
```

This is very common issue you might face when you write code in python after a gap.

Hope that helps.